# Trigger from local sql database to azure sql db

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-sql-database

I have a local and an Azure database. 
When a row is inserted in the local db, I would like it to insert it in the Azure one. I have created a trigger on the local db for that task:

```sql
USE [db_local] 
Create trigger [dbo].[trigInverse] on [dbo].[db_local]
after insert
 as 
begin
  insert into [serverazure.DATABASE.WINDOWS.NET].[db_azure].[Access].[Companies]([CompanyName])
  select NAME
from inserted;
end
```

However, when I try to insert a row the error in picture1 appears

[image]

I cannot see what the parameter is, and how to set a correct value in that error message.

I did some tests to find the cause: I put that trigger between 2 local db, and tried adding rows to the source db, and it works
In the linked server node, these are the settings

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Azure SQL Data Sync, download and install in your local server [SQL Azure Data Sync Agent](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27693)

Then setup your azure data base like this:

[Getting Started with Azure SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync)

It will sync your databases every 5 minutes.

Comment: Thank you very much Wilson, I will try this. Can it sync only specific columns in the table?

Comment: Yes, you can. Here explain this: [Step 3 - Configure sync group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync#step-3---configure-sync-group) If it was useful please mark as answer. :D